# Trouble compiling a program using an archive (.a)

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, unix-ar

**When I try to compile my file using a library *(.a),* I get *'fatal error: URLInputStream.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
'*.** I'm still pretty new to C++, and this seems so simple but I can't get it to work.

Compilation commands I've tried:

```
g++ inc/Downloader.h lib/libcs240utils.a
g++ inc/Downloader.h -L lib -l cs240utils
g++ inc/Downloader.h -Llib -lcs240utils
g++ src/Downloader.cpp -I inc -L lib -l cs240utils 
g++ -c src/Downloader.cpp -I inc -L lib -l cs240utils
```

How I compile my archive:

```
make lib
g++ -c -o utils/obj/CommandRunner.o utils/src/CommandRunner.cpp -I utils/inc
g++ -c -o utils/obj/FileInputStream.o utils/src/FileInputStream.cpp -I utils/inc
g++ -c -o utils/obj/FileSystem.o utils/src/FileSystem.cpp -I utils/inc
g++ -c -o utils/obj/HTMLToken.o utils/src/HTMLToken.cpp -I utils/inc
g++ -c -o utils/obj/HTMLTokenizer.o utils/src/HTMLTokenizer.cpp -I utils/inc
g++ -c -o utils/obj/HTTPInputStream.o utils/src/HTTPInputStream.cpp -I utils/inc
g++ -c -o utils/obj/StringUtil.o utils/src/StringUtil.cpp -I utils/inc
g++ -c -o utils/obj/URLInputStream.o utils/src/URLInputStream.cpp -I utils/inc
ar cr lib/libcs240utils.a utils/obj/*.o
```

The archive seems to be built correctly:

```
ar t lib/libcs240utils.a 

CommandRunner.o
FileInputStream.o
FileSystem.o
HTMLToken.o
HTMLTokenizer.o
HTTPInputStream.o
StringUtil.o
URLInputStream.o
```

I've also tried various options in `ar`.  If I specify an include path `-I utils/inc` then it will compile and work properly, so the file I want does work properly.  I've read numerous articles and questions here on StackOverflow, and I can't seem to see what I'm doing incorrectly.  **Any ideas or suggestions?**

*Note: I'm compiling a header which seems weird.  It was originally split into `.cpp` and `.h`, but to simplify problem solving I merged them.  This same error happened when they were split as well: `g++ src/Downloader.cpp -I inc -L lib -l cs240utils`*

Comment: What file is it complaining about? BTW, compiling a `.h` is unusual.

Comment: Added note about compiling the `.h`.  You guys seem caught up on this: the problem is NOT that I'm compiling a `.h` file.  It's the same result when I had it split.

Comment: What file does it say can't be found?  The .a, or the .h?  The fact that you mention that "-I utils/inc" makes it work would lead me to think that Downloader.h references stuff in that header.  You still need the header for compilation even when you have a static lib as part of the link step.

Comment: The archive is a red herring here.

Comment: Why are you passing headers to `g++`?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal You've got to be kidding me. . . did you even read the whole post? I've already explained this

Comment: @Levi: I'm saying it again because you ignored it. You seem to think you know better than everyone else, even though you're here with a problem you can't solve. Might want to give that some thought.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I am not truly attempting to compile a `.h` file.  It is in reality split on my system, but I combined them to potentially simplify the problem.  I have my answer and it has nothing to do with compiling a `.h`, thank you very much!

Comment: @Levi: I never said that the answer to the question was related, which is why I wrote a _comment_ not an _answer_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Downloader.h still likely needs header files to talk to types/classes/etc. in your static library.

The fact that you mention that "-I utils/inc" makes it work would lead me to think that Downloader.h references stuff in that header. You still need the header for compilation even when you have a static lib as part of the link step.

Comment: This does not seem to be what I have read.  However, there are tons of articles on ar and g++, so it's quite hard to search through them.  I'll take your word for it.

Comment: You have misread.  .a files are glorified collection of .o files.  You still need the headers just as you would with any other library or object file.  This is why every library and SDK in the world ships both object code (usually .a and/or .so, for static/shared variants) and the header files to use them.